# How can I skip the Google sign in if already logged in?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have one question, so I successfully implemented the Sing in with Google but I want to skip the login activity if I am already logged in and I can't understand how to do it, I already checked the internet for a solution but I was not able to implement it... Can anyone help me with this? I am new to Android.

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
    package com.example.ipill;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "LogIn";
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    SignInButton signInButton;
    TextView name;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    Context context = null;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        name =findViewById(R.id.name);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signIn();

                        break;
                }
            }
        });



        fetchLocation();
        statusCheck();

    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

            } catch (ApiException e) {

                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);

            }
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());


                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            System.out.println("TEST");
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    private void fetchLocation() {


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Required Location Permission")
                        .setMessage("You have to give this permission to acess this feature")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }


    }

    //Check location
    public void statusCheck() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        }
    }

    //If location is OFF -> Pop UP message to active it
    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Check your login status in onCreate() before building your GoogleSignIn instance. If your user is already logged in, you should not be executing the GoogleSignIn code at all.

Comment: hello have you made any changes at console or gmail login was working?

Comment: I didn't change anything, Gmail login was working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred logic would be if you are having a HomeActivity (Set it as a launcher activity in Manifest)

> In HomeActivity onCreate:

```
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser==null)
{
 startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
}
```

So everytime you launch HomeActivity. If user is null, you redirect the user to MainActivity. 
If user is signed in ,you redirect to HomeActivity.
The session is managed by firebase itself. No need to create SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

whenever your sign in or login process completes then save the user data (like user name, 
 email, mobile etc. whatever you want any time while app use) in shared preference or other database you prefer in your app.

On splash screen check if users saved data is available or not, if available then skip login activity and move user to direct home activity, otherwise take user to do login first.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a `Splash_Screen`. You can check your `Session` every time. If you have session you don't need to show `Login` Page or if you have no `Session` then you forward user to `Login` page.

Make one class for your `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class Session {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public Session(Context cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    }

    public void setusename(String usename) {
        prefs.edit().putString("usename", usename).commit();
    }

    public String getusename() {
        String usename = prefs.getString("usename","");
        return usename;
    }
}
```

In `onActivityResult':

```
private Session session;//global variable
```

then initialize it in `onCreate()`:

```
session = new Session(cntx); //in oncreate




@Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);


           //and now we set sharedpreference then use this like

              session.setusename("USERNAME");
           // from data you can get username

            } catch (ApiException e) {

                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);

            }
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
```

Now you can check this `Preference` in your `Splash` Screen:
First initiate your `Preferences` in `Splash` screen. Then call from `onCreate`:

```
if(prefs.getUserName ! = null && prefs.getUserName != ""){
   //Go to the your app main screen
}else{
   // Go to the login screen
}
```